# Custom type/object in visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce, email

Hi is it possible to use custom object as the recipientType in visualforce email template rather than the standard objects like User, Contact and Lead?

Answer (score 0):

No, the recipientType cannot be a custom object. A recipient must be a "person", which is a User, Lead, Contact, or Person Account. You can specify a "relatedTo" that may be any any standard or custom object that allows activities.

Comment: Thanks, I have the Attendee custom object (which is a "person") that I want to use as the recipientType. I want to send an email every time a attendee signs up an event, so in the email body it will need to have related list from the attendee as well. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnnySitu You can't define a custom "person" type. Call it a limitation of the platform. You'll need to use a design that leverages either leads or contacts. You can still use the attendee object to link a contact or lead to an event, but you'll need to rethink your current design.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, If you are using custom controller and custom method to send email then you can use the custom object as the recipientType.

I have used custom object as a recipientType and it's working for me but yes i just want to be clear that i have used custom object using custom apex class and custom method,

Please see below piece of code that i used on my custom command button,

```
public PageReference SendPdfEmail()
{       

    try{

        EmailTemplate template = [Select Id from EmailTemplate where Name='Test PDF'];
        String emailURL = '/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p3_lkid=' + CustomObjId + '&template_id=' + template.Id + '&retURL=%2F' + CustomObjId + '&p2_lkid=' +CustomObj.Contact_Name__c;

        PageReference quotePage = new PageReference(emailURL);
        quotePage.setRedirect(true);
        return quotePage;       

    }Catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }

}
```

Hope it helps you out !!

Comment: "p3" is the "related to" field, not the "recipient" field.